# Regex to read a class file

Tags: regex

I am looking for a Regex to read a c# class file like

```
MyClass{}
```

The regex shld return "MyClass" when passed the string "MyClass{}".

**Edited:**

```
Common
{
  MyClass1
  {
    Method1
    {
      "Helloworld";
      "GoodBye";     
    }
    Method2
    {
      "SayGoodMorning";
    }
  }
  MyClass2
  {
    Method3
    {
      "M3";
    }
  }
}
```

Actually i have to read a hierarchy like above, there can b n number of it and have to read before and inside {}

Comment: Are you sure you want such a simple RegEx? Perhaps you can add more details to the question, as with your description you might as well do `if (str == "MyClass{}") return "MyClass";`

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward regexp (Tim has provided a good solution w/ explanation), but I know regexps can be pretty intimidating for beginners, so here's a good resource that will teach you everything you need to know to be competent in regexps: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html

Just start from the "Characters" chapter and read them in order. It's a terrific resource.

Comment: Yes its not that simple rightly said by Oded, actually its a complete c# like file starting from namespce, classes in namespaces, methods etc. and I would be needing to do this in hierarchy way

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine supports lookahead, then you can use

```
\b[^{\s]+(?=\s*\{)
```

This will match `["Common", "MyClass1", "Method1", "Method2", "MyClass2", "Method3"]` in your example.

Explanation:

`\b`: Start the match at a word boundary.

`[^{\s]+`: Match one or more characters except opening braces or whitespace.

`(?=\s*\{)`: Assert that the match ends with a character that is followed by optional whitespace (including linebreaks) and an opening brace.

Restricting matches to certain hierarchy levels (in this case, only match at the second level of nesting) is not possible with regular expressions in general. It may be possible in certain regex dialects, but this is stretching the limits of what regexes are designed for - a parser would suit this better.